# Making the text transition smoother

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got this `<span>` of text on my website. What I want to do here is make this text **increase** in `font-size` when it is **hovered over**. I used the usual `transition: 1s font-size ease`, but that just makes it a *really rough transition*. I want to make it go *smoothly*, so that it doesn't make micro intervals in the middle.

Here's my HTML+CSS, trimmed to the said `element`:

```css
span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: 1s font-size ease;
 }
span:hover {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<span>Aravind's Site</span>
```

And BTW, no jQuery, please, unless ***absolutely necessary***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of *transforming* `font-size` you can use `scale` along with `transition`:

1. Add these `transition` rules to `span`:

   ```
   transition: transform 1s ease;
   display: inline-block;
   transform-origin: left;
   ```
2. On hover use `transform: scale(1.5)`

```css
span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: left;
 }
span:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<span>Aravind's Site</span>
```

Comment: this the most suitable solution without adding additional libraries, it blurs the text a little bit while transitioning especially on webkit but still good enough. I saw an answer suggesting the addition of `backface-visibility: hidden;` and `transform: translateZ(0);` to your css. but I think using SVG might produce sharper transition and edges.

Comment: Like @MaherFattouh said, it causes a really bad blur in my browser, you can't even read it (because of the font, i guess). MaherFattouh can you post your answer? It seems useful.

Comment: @MaherFattouh's solution worked for me. The blur's gone.